# Why is CPU performance calculated in frequencies instead of Mbit/s?

Tags: cpu

Why is CPU performance calculated as a frequency, instead of megabits per second? Frequencies are less common in computer terminology.

Comment: performance is measured by FLOPS, not mbps. And there's no mbps unit either, only MBps or Mbps

Comment: How are millibits relevant to CPUs?

Comment: Can you give an example or a reference? I've never seen CPU performance calculated in a frequency. Perhaps you're confusing the actual value of the CPU frequency for a performance measurement.

Answer (score 5):

For reliable operation, many digital integrated circuits, including CPUs, use a pulse generator, called a clock, which generates a train of pulses.  The various *and, or, nor*, etc, logic gates in the IC sense their inputs and update their outputs in according to which part of pulse train they see.  The clock speed is limited because it takes time for logic gates to update their output and it takes time for their output signals to travel from one part of the circuit to another before the next update occurs.  IC manufacturers will specify a maximum clock frequency at which an IC will run reliably.  Consequently, it is natural to classify the speed of an logic circuit by its clock frequency.

On the other hand, how many "bits per second" are transferred depends on what the CPU is doing.  If it is doing a NOP, it may be transferring no bits at all.  If it is transferring bits, the speed often depends more on where the bits are coming from or going to than it does on the CPU.  So, bits-per-second is not a natural way to classify CPU speeds.

As a measure of CPU speed, though, clock speed is just part of the story.  Some CPUs accomplish more things in one clock cycle than others do.  So, if one wanted to know how many [FLoating point OPerations per Second (FLOPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) a CPU can do, one divides the clock speed by the the number of clock cycles required 
to accomplish some floating point operation.  This sort of measure can be more meaningful than raw clock speed.

Because the clock frequency is well-defined whether the CPU is busy doing arithmetic or lazily transferring data to a peripheral, it is natural for electrical engineers to classify CPUs by their clock frequency.

#### So, how fast does a CPU move bits?

To illustrate the complexity of defining bits-per-second for a CPU, here is [a table](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~aofallon/ee234/handouts/x86times.pdf) of the number of clock cycles required to complete a data transfer for some of the many data transfer operations in the venerable 8086 CPU:
[image]
As you can see, some data transfer operations in the 8086 could take as few 
2 clock cycles, some took over 16 cycles to complete.  Consequently, bits-per-second is not a well-defined number even for this limited range of CPU instructions.

Comment: Basically, "bits" is not a measure of what a CPU does per "MHz" or cycle.  Mbit/sec makes more sense for a communications medium, whose job is dedicated to outputting bits.  A CPU busy calculating might output nothing for a while, but it's still doing something (and typically many somethings) on each cycle.  There also may be situations where it's doing nothing due to an exception, stall, I/O operation, etc.  But the cycles are still occurring.

Answer (score 1):

No, frequencies are very part of computer studies. For the CPU point of view, mbps would just be an inadequate measurement.

If you go down to electronics, and the electricity level of electronics there has to be some sort of synchronisation mechanism.

Say we have 2-bit adder:

```
C 1 0
C 1 1
-----
1 0 1

C is Carry, with initial carry=0, 

00+11 produces Resulting Carry = 0,
10+11 produces Resulting Carry = 1; basic maths.
```

right? But, what is 0, what is 1? And the exact question is `WHEN the electronics decide that there is a 0/1 on the line?` So, before go further let me draw the scheme of that bacis adder:

[image: Basic 2-Bit adder]

There are actually two questions in above question given. First one is `WHEN`, second one is `the decision of data`. From the example `when` AdderX `decides` there is a 0/1 on the line Xn or Yn, since they came from some other circuit's output. And `what is 0, what is 1?` They're just voltages!.. The CPU point of view 1,25V is logic-1 and anything below that is logic-0. So, `the decision` of 1,25V is equals to logic-1 is called `Sampling`. And `when` to that decision is called `synchronisation`.

From here, the adders has to sample the voltages one the x, y and c lines to drive them through the logic, and has to decide the timing. That is because, basicly: `the data, actually the voltage can change in time!`:

Drive 1,25 volts to line y1. It is **not** 1,25V **instantly**. It gradients.. Or take 1,25 volts to 0, it is not 0V instantly. Gradient ascent/descent is measured in picoseconds (10^-12) in some cirtuits, nanoseconds (10^-9) in some. Because of this gradiation, integrated circuits -> the logic gates -> the transistors **DELAY**.

Back to adders. Imagine the sampling is done continously, but the question is the decide whether it is the right sample or wrong. When this gate is producing the right result? Here the sync is coming in. Giving enough time to gate and then sample it's output. How is that done? There is a `Clock`! Remember `The System Timer`? And that timer is on the mother board?

By this clock, every, I mean **every** IC in the CPU is synced. Going further, you could have noticed that the frequency of system timer, say 133-Mhz, and we are talking about 2.4-GHz CPUs. That is because, since CPUs can work faster than MBs, they basicly multiply the SysTimer by 15 to 20, the CPU Multiplier.

Since CPU is completely synced with that timer frequency, is it possible to calculate 0 + 1 faster then that frequency? No; it is not. So, it is true when we say `a CPU can do ONE job per ONE timer tick`: `cylce`.

Imagine moving 1-Byte from memory to CPU. It is done by several jobs. So it is done by several clock cycles. Say it is 5 cycle. How many move operations can be done in 1sec then? But, here comes the killer part: how about a sum operation? There have to be 2 operands, they happen to be in the memory and needed to move to the CPU, then make the calculations, store back the result, etc. Say that op is done by 21 cyles. But hey, I had done with 8-bit in 5 cycles but 24-bit (8-bit op1, 8-bit op2, 8-bit result) in 21! Souldn't it be 15?

What about instruction fetching? Micro-instructions.. This goes waaay beyond deeper..

What about actual operations in different CPUs with same clock frequency? For example, given the same specs, frequency, cache etc, how many cycles does it take to do the most difficult operation, the division? One can do 5/2 in 10 cycles, the other can do in 8. So freq. is enough? Sadly, no. And this is where the `FLOPS (Floating Point Operations per Second)` comes in.

So, summing up:

Xbps is just not enough, not accurate. It has to be more spesific and more accurate. Frequency measurement is spesific but not accurate either. FLOPS is both spesific and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solid answers provided by John1024 and The_aLiEn, I'd like to point out a bigger problem with using mbps.  It's a meaningless measurement in this situation.

Firstly, data throughput is a product of frequency and width.  Since different buses within the system layout have different bit widths, the measurements are weird.

Secondly, different parts of the system work at different frequencies but a single clock.  The Phase Lock Loop frequency scaler is much easier to understand when it's a frequency... 3.3 Ghz is actually 300Mhz x 11.

Thirdly, even allowing for the fact instructions take different amounts of time, different instructions have different amounts of input and output, such that the data throughput would be dependant on what you were trying to do even though it was at 100% utilisation.

Fourthly, modern CPUs use a pipeline approach such that it's concurrently processing multiple instructions.  How well it can handle pipelining instructions depends on the actual instructions being processed.

Frequency is the key measurement for most chips rather than FLOP, MIPS or Mbps simply because clock frequency is the lowest common denominator for circuits: It always has a sensible meaning.